# Searching in large PDF files. What technology to use?

Tags: python, pdf, elasticsearch, search, indexing

I have a side project where I have about 1000 text only PDF files (Average size around 500 kb) on which dataset I want to do fast free text searching. The search results should at least tell the matched text, the PDF File which contained the matched text and optionally the location in the PDF.

*Does this project sound like a good candidate for cloud hosted elastic search? Or would that be an overkill for this data size? Shall I just go with Apache Lucene and put that in my own web server? Or something completely different?*

I would also like to put a UI in front of this functionality. I am no UI developer and our team is really lacking in UI expertise.

*Can you suggest some NoUI framework that generates a UI in front of a Rest API endpoint? Is there such a thing?*

Our language preference is python in this team as the common divisor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an applicant tracking system which has more than 20,000 CV and the best approach for you is ElasticSearch, Because:

> 1. very high performance
> 2. 100% accuracy for searching
> 3. very easy to use with simplest APIs
> 4. easy to backup with replicas

And I recommend to use ElasticSearch amazon service [ES](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/).

And about UI framework I just use JavaScript with [FineUploader](https://fineuploader.com/) what hepled me a lot with chunking and parallel upload.